# Circular dependency in C++ template methods

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a problem with a circular dependecy in C++ template methods. I realize there are several similar threads here but they didn't help me with my specific case. This here is a nonsensical example, but it illustrates the issue:

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
int main()
{
    float f = 10;
    A a;
    a.foo( f );
}
```

A.h

```
#pragma once

#include "B.h"
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:
    B _b;

public:
    A() {}

    std::string getName() const { return "A"; }

    template<typename T> void foo( T t )
    {
        if( _b.getActive() )
            _b.foo( t, this );
        else
            std::cout << "A, " << t << std::endl;
    }
};
```

B.h

```
#pragma once

#include "A.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A;

class B
{
private:
    bool _active;

public:
    B() : _active( false ) {}

    bool getActive() const { return _active; }
    void setActive( bool active ) { _active = active; }

    template<typename T> void foo( T t, const A *a )
    {
        std::cout << "B, " << a->getName() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

In B.h I can neither forward-declare A (will get `error C2039: 'getName': is not a member of 'A'`), nor include A.h (will get `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.`).

Is there a way around this or do I have to completely refactor my code?

**EDIT**

I'm compiling with MSVC 141 (VS 2017) with `/std:c++latest`, btw.

Comment: Interestingly, it compiles with GCC without errors, but Clang doesn't like this code.

Comment: That's indeed interesting. I'm currently on Visual Studio, I updated my post for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `getName()` in `a->getName()` is a non-dependent name (it does not depend on the template parameter `T`), and it is resolved at the point of template definition. But `A` is incomplete at that point.

As a simple but ugly [workaround](https://godbolt.org/z/k8uwgK), we can introduce a fake dependency on `T`:

```
template<class T, class S>
struct First {
    using Type = T;
};

struct A;

struct B {
    template<typename T>
    void foo(T t, const typename First<A, T>::Type* a) {
        std::cout << "B, " << a->getName() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

---

A cleaner solution is to move `foo()` definitions outside classes and include them after both `A` and `B`:

```
// A.h
#pragma once
#include "B.h"

class A {
    // ...
    template<typename T>
    void foo(T t);
};

// A_impl.h
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

template<typename T>
void A::foo(T t) {
    // ...
}

// Similar for B.h and B_impl.h

// main.cpp
#include "A_impl.h"
#include "B_impl.h"

int main() {
    float f = 10;
    A a;
    a.foo(f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like the latter solution, that's quite elegant, I wasn't aware of that possibility, but makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

I'd also like to add a (not so nice) solution, but maybe it's helpful for some:

during investigations it struck me that I had a different project using the same code base which does compile without any issues. I noticed the difference was the new project had the [Conformance Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VC.Project.VCCLCompilerTool.ConformanceMode)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=vs-2019) set to `/permissive-`, while the old one had not. So if you need a quick solution for MSVC and don't care about standard conformance, you may want to turn this option off. This way, the above code works just as posted.

**EDIT**

Disclaimer: be aware though that this may break code, as Evg points out in the comment below.

Comment: And the reason for this is that in the old days Microsoft C++ compiler just consumed templates as a sequence of tokens and did not implement two-phase name lookup at all. `/permissive-` can break some code that relies on two-phase lookup. See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/) for some details.